# Expected squared prediction error derivation

Tags: machine-learning, error

I'm reading *The Elements of Statistical Learning* by T.Hastie I'm stuck on deriving EPE (formula 2.27) in 2.4 Statistical Decision Theory. Exercise 2.5(a)
In parallel I'm reading *A Solution Manual and Notes for: The Elements of Statistical Learning by Jerome Friedman..* But it doesn't help in that case.

[image]
[image]

Well I have two questions here but I will demonstrate what I did. Perhaps it helps to get my point.

$$EPE(x_{0}) = E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}E_{τ}(y_{0}-\hat{y}_{0}) = $$
$$E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[E_{τ}(y^{2}_0)-(E_{τ}(y_0))^{2}+E_{τ}(\hat{y}^{2}_0)-(E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0))^{2}+(E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0)-y_0)^{2}|x_0] = $$
$$E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[E_{τ}(y^{2}_0)|x_0]-E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[(E_{τ}(y_0))^{2}|x_0]+E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[E_{τ}(\hat{y}^{2}_0)|x_0]-E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[(E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0))^{2}|x_0]+E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[(E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0)-y_0)^{2}|x_0] = $$
$$E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[y^{2}_0|x_0]-(E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[y_0|x_0])^2+E_{τ}(\hat{y}^{2}_0)-(E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0))^{2}+(E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0)-E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[y_0|x_0])^{2} = $$
$$Var(x_0|y_0) + Var(\hat{y}_0) - Bias^2(\hat{y}_0)$$

I'm done this so far. Probably with mistakes.

1. I don't understand why Bias is 0. There is a little explanation In *A Solution Manual and Notes* book(page 9, Ex.2.5 Part(a)). The clue formula is in bottom of the image below. Why expected value of prediction is equal to $x^{T}_{0}$ multiplied by vector of errors?
   [image]
2. How to derive $Var_{τ}(\hat{y}_0) = E_{τ}(x^{T}_{0}(X^{T}X)^{-1}x_{0}σ^{2}))$ from 2.27 formula?

Any hints or links will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Equation 2.27 and Exercise 2.5 cover a lot of ground. It is easy to tell this, because Exercise 2.5 references Chapter 3, a future chapter. For example, Chapter 3 is where the $\beta$s come from in the proposed solution. It is where least squares is covered in detail. The wiki article on [Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) uses the same notation and is pretty good.

I'm going to breakdown the problem in incredible detail because I think those answers are best and it is the way I think.

The expression of interest is,
\begin{equation}
EPE(x_{0})=E_{y_0|x_0}E_\tau \big( y_0 - \hat{y}_0 \big)^2.
\tag{1}\label{problem2.27}
\end{equation}

This is different from the MSE (Equation 2.25) because the problem defined in Equation 2.26 has a random variable ($\varepsilon$), so when a $x_0$ is selected a random number is pulled from the distribution of $\varepsilon$.

The problem is defined such that we have a training set $\tau$ that contains N examples each of $x_i, y_{i}$ and $\varepsilon_{i}$. The problem tells us that we know the relationship between these values is,
\begin{equation}
y_{i}=x_{i}^{T}\beta+\varepsilon_{i},
\end{equation}
where $\beta$ is the true parameters that we want to estimate given the N data points in the training set $\tau$. OLS says that those estimated parameters are,
\begin{equation}
\hat\beta=\beta+(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon,
\end{equation}
where $X$ is the design matrix (all the N training points $x_{i}$ turned into an N x p  matrix), and $\tilde\varepsilon$ is a N x 1 vector of the actual errors in the training data. These are specific values that have been pulled from the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, they are normally distributed, but they are not random. This distinction is important because $E_{\tau}$ acts on $\tilde\varepsilon$ and $E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}$ acts on $\varepsilon$.

With the definitions out of the way, we can tackle Eq. \eqref{problem2.27} (2.27 from the book). As defined in the problem, we are given $x_0$, so we can estimate $\hat y_{0}=x_{0}^{T}\hat\beta=x_{0}^{T}\beta+x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon$, and we know from 2.26 that $y_{0}=x_{0}^{T}\beta+\varepsilon$. You can see right away that $y_{0}-\hat y_{0}$ does not have $\beta$ in it, they subtract out, so the fact that we don't know the true parameters $\beta$ doesn't matter. But we will take the longer route through Equation 2.25 to pull out the Bias and Variance separately.

Starting from the middle line in Equation 2.25, and noting that $f(x_{0})=y_{0}$, we can rewrite Eq. \eqref{problem2.27} as,
\begin{equation}
EPE(x_{0})=E_{y_0|x_0}\big[ E_{\tau}[\hat y_{0}-E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0})]^{2}  + [E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0}) - y_{0}]^{2} \big],
\tag{2}\label{inter2.27}
\end{equation}
where it is explicit that $E_{\tau}y_{0}=y_{0}$. The first term is the variance, so we turn to the second term and take the $E_{y_0|x_0}$ with us because it will not affect the variance.

\begin{equation}
E_{y_0|x_0}[E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0}) - y_{0}]^{2} = E_{y_0|x_0}[E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0}) - x_{0}^{T}\beta - \varepsilon]^{2}=E_{y_0|x_0}[(E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0}) - x_{0}^{T}\beta)^2 + \varepsilon^{2} - 2\varepsilon(E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0}) - x_{0}^{T}\beta)],
\end{equation}
the first term here is the bias from Equation 2.25. It is not affected by $E_{y_0|x_0}$, while $E_{y_0|x_0}\varepsilon^2=\sigma^{2}$ and $E_{y_0|x_0}\varepsilon=0$ as defined by the distribution. Plugging this back into Eq. \eqref{inter2.27} we are left with,

\begin{equation}
EPE(x_{0})=E_{\tau}[\hat y_{0}-E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0})]^{2} + (E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0}) - x_{0}^{T}\beta)^2 + \sigma^{2},
\end{equation}
which is the variance, the bias and the 'additional variance' respectively.

Using $E_{\tau}\hat y_{0}=x_{0}^{T}\beta$ because $\tilde\varepsilon$ is pulled from $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ so $E_{\tau}\tilde\varepsilon=0$, it is immediately obvious the the bias is 0.

For your second question we have to look at the variance term,
\begin{equation}
Var_{\tau}(\hat y_{0})=E_{\tau}[\hat y_{0}-E_{\tau}(\hat y_{0})]^{2}=E_{\tau}[x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon]^{2}.
\end{equation}
It is important to note here that the term inside the brackets [] is a scalar, which can be verified by counting the dimensions of the matrices and vectors (as defined above) or noting that $\hat y_{0}$ is a scalar, so all terms in its definition must be too. Since they are scalars we can multiply them in any order, so we can write,

\begin{equation}
E_{\tau}[x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon]^{2} = E_{\tau}[(x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon)(x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon)^{T}] = E_{\tau}[x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon\varepsilon^{T}X(X^T X)^{-1}x_{0}],
\end{equation}
where, as discussed before, $E_{\tau}$ only affects the $\varepsilon$, specifically $E_{\tau}\varepsilon\varepsilon^{T}=\sigma^{2}I_{N}$ and $I_{N}$ is the identity matrix of size N x N. Putting that together gives,
\begin{equation}
= E_{\tau}[x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}\tilde\varepsilon\tilde\varepsilon^{T}X(X^T X)^{-1}x_{0}] = x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}X^{T}E_{\tau}[\tilde\varepsilon\tilde\varepsilon^{T}]X(X^T X)^{-1}x_{0} = x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}(X^{T}X)(X^T X)^{-1}x_{0}\sigma^{2} = x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}x_{0}\sigma^{2}.
\end{equation}

Which is just about the result in 2.27. I'm not sure how $E_{\tau}x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}x_{0}$ is different from $x_{0}^{T}(X^T X)^{-1}x_{0}$ because X is a design matrix that is deterministic. The solution you include from "A Solution and Notes" also seems to ignore this distinction. I don't think there is much to learn about the format of the variance in 2.27 beyond "if you write the result this way, you get this format".

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my questions. Looks like I realized how to derive the formula for the first question. But I'm halfway for the second one.

1. $Bias^2(\hat{y}_{0}) = (E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0)-E_{y_{0}|x_{0}}[y_0|x_0])^{2} = (E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0)-x^{T}_{0}β)^{2} \text{- it is already known}$
   $E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0) = x^{T}_{0}E_{τ}(\hatβ) \text{ - to find expected y we need minimize error}$
   $x^{T}_{0}E_{τ}(\hatβ) = x^{T}_{0}β \text{ - because }\hatβ=β+(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}ε = β \text{ and }E_{τ}(\hatβ)=β\text{ taking into account that } E_{τ}(ε)=0 \text{ by Gauss-Markov assumptions}$
   So $E_{τ}(\hat{y}_0) = x^{T}_{0}E_{τ}(\hatβ) = x^{T}_{0}β$ and $Bias^2(\hat{y}_{0}) = (x^{T}_{0}β-x^{T}_{0}β)^{2} = 0^2 = 0$
2. Still stuck. I'm not sure that I'm doing this right but I've come to this so far.
   $Var_{τ}(\hat{y}_0) = Var_{τ}(x^{T}_{0}\hat{β}) = x^{T}_{0}Var_{τ}(\hat{β})=x^{T}_{0}(X^{T}X)^{-1}σ^{2}=???$